# An equivalence between projective modules over the preprojective algebra and an orbit category

Tags: triangulated-categories, quivers, preprojective-algebra

Let $Q$ be a Dynkin quiver, and let $kQ$ be its path algebra over some field k. Let $\Pi$ be the preprojective algebra of $Q$. Then (c.f. Section 7.3 of Keller's [On Triangulated Orbit Categories](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503240v4.pdf)) the category $\text{proj } \Pi$ of projective $\Pi$-modules is equivalent to the orbit category $\mathcal{D}^b(kQ)/\tau$. Does this equivalence still hold if $Q$ is replaced by a disjoint union of Dynkin quivers?

Comment: For a start, what does the path algebra of a quiver with several connected components look like, as compared to the path algebras of the components? From there, it's a question of whether objects of the derived category decompose in a similar way.  The obvious question is whether you get "cross terms".  Some thinking about e.g. A_2 union A_2 should establish the general case, I'd expect.